# Minor styling tweaks to Trustpilot widget

Tags: javascript, css

Please see a replication of the Trustpilot widget in use at this [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zigojacko/G8CLx/).

Was hoping to be able to override the widget's CSS to make these tweaks but have not been successful in finding a way to do so as of yet.

The only styles that I wish to change are removing the border, changing the width of widget to 250px and center aligning the widget - all on class (`.tp-box`) which is loaded via an iframe.

As per the JSfiddle linked to above, the code in use...

## Markup

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <div class="block block-tp-reviews">
        <div class="tp_-_box" data-tp-settings="domainId:313478">
            <a href="http://www.trustpilot.co.uk/review/www.showermania.co.uk" rel="nofollow" hidden>Showermania Reviews</a>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function () { var a = "https:" == document.location.protocol ? "https://ssl.trustpilot.com" : "http://s.trustpilot.com", b = document.createElement("script"); b.type = "text/javascript"; b.async = true; b.src = a + "/tpelements/tp_elements_all.js"; var c = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; c.parentNode.insertBefore(b, c) })();
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.sidebar .block-tp-reviews .tp-box {border: none !important; width: 250px !important;}
.sidebar .block-tp-reviews iframe {width: 250px;}
```

Is there a way that these styles can be overridden at all? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

CSS from the parent document will not be able to have any effect on anything loaded in the iframe, for a number of reasons.

1. Any attempt to modify the styling of the content within the iframe will violate [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).
2. The content within the iframe is not physically in the same document (page) as the surrounding HTML that makes up the iframe.

Short answer: No, these styles cannot be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/G8CLx/2/
I updated your example adding two styles:

```
.tpiframe-wrapper{width:176px;overflow:hidden;}
#tpiframe-box0{margin:-1px 0 0 -1px;}
```

It just hides border into the div.

Answer (score -3):

Trustpilot's widgets are developed using Bootstrap. Just like using Bootstrap you can select the div you want to change and style it according to your liking. If you add .tp-box to your style sheet or in  tags at the bottom of your html, you should be able to customize it however you want.